# Pushing a master branch to github repository after reset

Tags: git, github

So basically for whatever reason after merging my master branch with another branch and pushing master branch to github repo my code was filled with `<<<<<<< HEAD`
for whatever reason, even in places that I edited many commits ago so what I did was `git reset --hard` to the previous commit and that fixed the code now when I try to push my master branch to github repo I get

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'my github repo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

now doing `git pull` would just give me the code that's filled `<<<<<<HEAD`
which I don't need.
So I looked for some solutions and the first few results suggested `git push -f origin branch` but when I do that I get

```
error: src refspec branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to my github repo
```

so what should I do now, lads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it myself

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

does the trick.